# Hadoop Looping the Reducer

Tags: java, loops, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to find a way to "loop" my reducer, for example:

```
for(String document: tempFrequencies.keySet())
{
if(list.get(0).equals(document))
{
testMap.put(key.toString(), DF.format(tfIDF));
}
}
//This allows me to create a hashmap which i plan to write out to context as Filename = key then all of the terms weights = value (a list I can parse out in the next job)
```

The code currently will run through the entire reduce and give me what I want for list.get(0) but the problem is once it is finished doing that entire reduce I need it to start again for list.get(1) etc.  Any ideas on how to loop the reduce phase after it has finished?

Comment: I'll reformulate. Is this question particular to the hadoop framework? If so, could you give more background.

Comment: During the reduce state of Hadoop it Loops for every key,value pair from the mapper.  So if I do what is suggested by Paul, itll simply run the code twice (or however many times I set the loop) for EVERY key, value pair.  What I need it to do is run the entire reduce (loop through for every key, value) output that result and then Loop starting again at the first key, value pair.  Until I have gotten the result for each document.

Comment: Ah ok. So if I understand things correctly you'd need to find a way to get back into the loop with updated values. Correct?

Comment: Pretty much,  In simplist terms.  I want it to run the entire Reduce then print the result.  Then start the reduce over on the next document.  So if I had 50 documents it would end up running the reduce code 50 times.

Comment: Well I did find a way to make it literally rerun the reducer everytime I just have to delete the assigned output folder everytime (becausee hadoop wont override it) so my real output will just have to be wrote to another folder.  Not sure if there really is another way to do this...because I really am wanting it to run the entire reducer for every document.

Comment: This framework sounds as complicated as Spring Batch. It's gotten me curious but I'm out of depth for now. I don't suppose you could something clever by swapping list.get(0) with a getter?

Answer (score 0):

Nest the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_time; i++){
//your code

}
```

Replace the 0 with i.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key-tag-value technique.
In mapper emit (key, 0, value) for list values and (key, 1, value) for documents (?). In reducer values will be grouped by key and tag and sorted by tag for each key. You should write your own grouping comparator (and custom partitioner).
PS I am using the same techique for graph processing. I can provide sample code after weekend.